# Updated Method signature is not working in wcf RESTful services

Tags: wcf, rest, methods, overloading, fiddler

I have a method like this

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "StrDetails", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<StrSearchDetails> StrDetails(string str1)
{
    List<StrSearchDetails> details = new List<StrSearchDetails> ();
    return details;
}
```

I am able to hit this method from Fiddler

I have updated and replaced like this

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "StrDetails", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<StrSearchDetails> StrDetails(string str1, string str2)
{
     List<StrSearchDetails> details = new List<StrSearchDetails> ();
     return details;
}
```

Not able to hit this method. Throwing 500 error in Fiddler.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you calling the method?

Comment: Fiddler call : http://localhost:1491/<servicename>/StrDetails. JSON Body :[ { FK : "TEST", SK : "TEST" } ] (URL will be constructing in backbone.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the uri template:

```
[WebInvoke(uriTemplate="/StrDetails?str1={str1}&str2={str2}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```